# VBA Modules and passing arguments

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a module that can be called from any part of my application to check if a particular font is installed on the users system, and if not - install the font and check again before continuing

**Main Applicaton**

```
if RequiredFont.Run(strFontName) = FALSE Then '(error message and exit sub)
```

**Module "RequiredFont"**

```
Public Function Run(Font As String) As Boolean
    if check(Font) = FALSE Then
        Run = FALSE
        Install(Font)
        if check(Font) = TRUE Then Run = TRUE
    Else
        Run = TRUE
    End If


Private Function Check(Font as String) as Boolean
'code to check the font exists on the users localmachine, returns true/false
End Sub

Private Sub Install(Font as String)
'code to install the font on the users localmachine,
End Sub
```

My first question is:

Is the best way to make arguments available to all functions and subs, to pass them through each time I call? (as shown above).... or is there a simple way to declare an argument as variable to the whole module when Run() is called?

My Second Question is:

Is there a way I can avoid Run() alltogether and just call the module name "RequiredFont" directly, I remember that in other languages, calling a sub by a certain name would automatically run that sub when the module is called

Thank You

EDIT - This is how my code looks now:

```
Private FontName As String
Private FontFile As String


Public Function Run(strFontName As String, strFontFile As String) As Boolean

    FontName = strFontName
    FontFile = strFontFile
    Run = False

    If CheckFont() = False Then InstallFont
    If CheckFont() = True Then
        Run = True
    Else
        'message error"
    End If

End Function


Private Function CheckFont() As Boolean
    'code to check if the font is installed
    On Error Resume Next
    'Create a temporary StdFont object
    With New StdFont
        ' Assign the proposed font name
        .Name = FontName
        ' Return true if font assignment succeded
        If (StrComp(FontName, .Name, vbTextCompare) = 0) = False Then
            CheckFont = False
        Else
            CheckFont = True
        End If
    End With
End Function

Private Sub InstallFont()
' code to install the font
    MsgBox "You need the following font installed to continue." _
    & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "'" & FontName & "'" _
    & vbNewLine _
    & vbNewLine & "Click OK to launch the font. Please click the INSTALL button at the top"
    OpenFile (PATH_TO_FONTS & FontFile)

End Sub
```

Comment: I want to suggest you run this check (and install the font if necessary) one time only, when your app is opened. Making a function continuously available can be a great idea, but it is over-complicated for what you want to do here.

Comment: The application will be used to open word templates and populate them with data from the database.... but each word template has different fonts and sometimes certain people wont be using that part of the application, so checking everytime they load up the program would be unnecessary if they never use that feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using function arguments is a good coding practise, that way you know exactly what goes in and what goes out a function.

You can however use a global variable, which would be set once when `Run` is called and still be accessible to the other functions.

```
'could also be Private to hide it from other modules
Public myFont As String

Public Function Run(Font As String) As Boolean
    myFont = Font
    '...
End Sub


Private Function Check() as Boolean
' you can access myFont here
End Sub

Private Sub Install()
'idem
End Sub
```

Regarding your second question, I don't think you can.

Comment: would this be code that would be better suited to a class module?

Comment: @IanJackson If you wanted to check multiple fonts then yes definitely, but for only one it just seem ineffective.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare optional functions, and set defaults:

```
Public Function fxMyFunction _
    (Optional lngProj As Variant, _
     Optional strFruit As Variant = "banana", _
     Optional booTest As Boolean = False) As String

   '' IsMissing requires that lngProj be a Variant
   booNoProject = IsMissing(lngProj)  

   fxMyFunction = strFruit

End Function
```

The `Optional` arguments must follow non-optional arguments.

### About functions that "run on inclusion"

You do have to call functions and subs by name.  There is no "self-running function" feature for a VBA standard module.  VBA "includes" all modules on compiling.

VBA class modules are where you will find the equivalent of constructors.  Investing in VBA's version of object-orientation doesn't seem helpful for your current need.  If you do go that direction, some aspects will start looking familiar to you (though perhaps just enough to get frustrating, as OO remains a feature that was added later and looks the part).

Answer (score 1):

As @z states, you can use a global variable, although this is bad practice.

Regarding question 2, you can give your function a unique name and omit naming your module to run it, e.g.

```
findOrInstallFont(Fontname)
```

Comment: Don't know why I didn't consider this.... Ill just name the main function "RequiredFont()" the same as the module, and since I wont be referencing a particular part of that module - it will never have to be rwuiredfont.requiredfont()

Comment: However, a good practice in general is to call functions explicitly by module.  It provides clarity later on.  I live by it.  So while I can imagine naming the "main" function after its module, I would still call it as `RequiredFont.RequiredFont()`.  In practice this would come out as `vbRequiredFont.RequiredFont()` because for me a short prefix to indicate the object type is another indispensible practice.  Again, specific to Access.